# http call inside of a controller which is inside of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I a have a servlet called TestServlet.java which returns some data (not important what it returns, just some text).

Here's the ng directive I'm creating:

```
(function() {
    var aMod = angular.module('aMod', []);

    aMod.directive('aDir', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            templateUrl : "test.html",
            controller : function() {
                this.test = 'this is a test variable';
                this.diranswer = 'Test: ';
                this.direrror;

                var req = {
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : '/test1/TestServlet',
                    params : {
                        p1 : 'test1',
                        p2 : 'test2'
                    }
                };
                $http(req).then(function(response) {
                    this.diranswer += response.data;
                    console.log(this.diranswer);
                }, function(response) {
                    this.direrror = response.data;
                });
            },
            controllerAs : "at"
        }
    })
})();
```

and here's the test.html file:

```
<div>
    this is a test partial html
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="at.test" />
    {{at.test}}
    <br>
    {{at.diranswer}}
    <br>
    {{at.direrror}}
</div>
```

I'm not being able to assign to at.diranswer the text returned by the servlet. Could you please help me out with this?

Thanks, 
Turik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` inside the `$http` callback is different than the `this` on which `diranswer` exists.  So, when you set it in the callback, you're setting it on a totally different object.  You need to save off the value before issuing the call:

```
var self = this;
$http(req).then(function(response) {
     self.diranswer += response.data;
     console.log(self.diranswer);
}, function(response) {
     self.direrror = response.data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot 'sma'. It's working now. I knew i'm messing around with 'this' but could not find out how to go about it.

Comment: Sure.  Glad to help.  Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: I don't see an 'accept' button or link, I just gave it a vote UP.

Comment: You should see a checkmark underneath the up/down arrows next to the question.